# Case Statement Failing

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, case

I have researched StackOverflow for some answer to composing a CASE statement within an SQL query.  The following is what I'm attempting:

```
select
chkdetail_t.check_acct,
chkheader_t.acct_number,
 CASE WHEN chkdetail_t.check_number = chkdetail_t.check_number THEN SUM(chkdetail_t.amount)
 END AS chek_total,
 chkdetail_t.check_number,
 convert(VARCHAR(10),CAST(chkdetail_t.check_date as datetime), 101) AS chk_date,
 chkdetail_t.amount,
 chkdetail_t.vend_name,
 chkdetail_t.chk_status,
 chkdetail_t.reconsiled,
 chkdetail_t.chk_type,
 chkdetail_t.apr_pay_amt,
 chkdetail_t.apr_disc_amt,
  chkdetail_t.apr_adj_amt
```

When I run the query I get the following error:

Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Column 'dbo.chkdetail_t.check_acct' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

My whole objective is to take the check numbers that equal themselves and sum up their total since vendor invoices are issued separately and we pay with one check.

I read another thread that had similar issues but the code I kept plugging in and reading the errors and attempting to fix the SQL query was not working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Sincerely, Mark

Comment: You are using `SUM` in your `CASE` without a `GROUP BY` and so the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select
chkdetail_t.check_acct,
chkheader_t.acct_number,
 SUM(CASE WHEN chkdetail_t.check_number = chkdetail_t.check_number THEN chkdetail_t.amount ELSE NULL END)  AS chek_total,
 chkdetail_t.check_number,
 convert(VARCHAR(10),CAST(chkdetail_t.check_date as datetime), 101) AS chk_date,
 chkdetail_t.amount,
 chkdetail_t.vend_name,
 chkdetail_t.chk_status,
 chkdetail_t.reconsiled,
 chkdetail_t.chk_type,
 chkdetail_t.apr_pay_amt,
 chkdetail_t.apr_disc_amt,
  chkdetail_t.apr_adj_amt
```

All the columns that are in select statement but not in any aggregate function will go in your GROUP BY Clause.

Comment: So I need to group by all of my columns except those in a function?

Comment: Yes , read here to learn more about [`Sql Server Aggregate`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213243(v=sql.80).aspx)

Comment: @user3390119 Not a problem and now you can accept the answer :)

Comment: Add the full query to your question please, its difficult to suggest a solution like this.

Comment: My apologies: From the select statement this is the remainder of the query: from dbo.chkdetail_t
join dbo.chkheader_t
on chkheader_t.check_acct = chkdetail_t.check_acct


where chkdetail_t.check_acct = 'HUNTINGTON'
and chkdetail_t.chk_status not in ('V', 'R')
and chkdetail_t.chk_type != 'R'
and chkdetail_t.reconsiled = 0

Comment: And I did fix the SUM() you showed me.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Ok. I went through the query and found a comma where it should not have been.  But now I'm back to the Group By clause error: Column 'dbo.chkdetail_t.check_acct' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Comment: Add `chkdetail_t.check_acct` column to your GROUP BY clause

Comment: Got it!!!  Thank you!!! Can I give you more points?!  I don't have enough reputation points yet.  Sorry.  Thank you again, though.